# Angular AuthGuard does not return UrlTree from inside subscription

Tags: angular, angular-guards

I am trying to implement `UrlTree` to redirect user if guard fails.
`this.authService.isAuthenticated()` returns observable.

The following does not work but it does console `false`.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
  this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log(isAuthenticated);
      return this.router.createUrlTree(['auth/sign-in']);
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

But the following works if I remove subscription:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
  return this.router.createUrlTree(['auth/sign-in']);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot return from inside subscribe (in any case). Route guard can return a boolean or an observable of a boolean. So in your case you need to return an observable of boolean. Worth mentioning also, in your current code, since this is async, what you are currently returning is **always** `false` no matter the logged in status, why? It takes x amount of time to get the authenticated status, so `false` is returned every time, angular does not wait for the response, just moves on to the next code available, which is `return false;` in your current code.

So, as said, return an observable, i.e use `map` instead of `subscribe`:

```ts
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ....

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      map(isAuthenticated => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
          return true;
        }
        // no need for else, if above is truthy, further code is not executed
        this.router.createUrlTree(['auth/sign-in']);
        return false;
      })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't know you need to redirect user. So use this functions:

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.authService.isAuthenticated().pipe(
             take(1),
             map(user => !!user), // Converting object to a boolean
             tap(loggedIn => {
                // If you not return any value
                // function will return loggedIn boolean value
                if (!loggedIn) {
                   this.router.navigate(['/login'])
                }
            })
      );
}
```

Comment: I tried your both solutions but it does not redirect.

Comment: Updated to redirect you need to use `.navigate()` function.

Comment: `.navigate()` works but not returning `UrlTree` which is introduced in Angular 7. I up vote your answer for your effort. Thanks

Comment: Try to use second variable `this.router.createUrlTree(['../login'], {relativeTo: XXX})`. Never used that functions.

Answer (score 0):

@AJT82 answer didn't work for me in Angular 8.
Returning a UrlTree with `parseUrl` and return a `true` is the only way it works.

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.auth$.pipe(
      map((authState: AuthState) => {
        console.log('=========root guard=============');
        if (!authState.isLoggedIn) {
          return this.router.parseUrl('/auth/login');
        }

        if (state.url === '' || state.url === '/') {
          if (authState.accessGroups.includes(AccessGroup.ADMIN)) {
            return this.router.parseUrl('/post/list');
          }
          if (authState.accessGroups.includes(AccessGroup.REEF)) {
            return this.router.parseUrl('/reef');
          }
        }
        return true;
      })
    );
```

And I don't really understand why returning the UrlTree is not enough. If I do not return the `true` the Router will be blocked. 
Very strange.

Setting the UrlTree and then returning True didn't work either. Only returning the `UrlTree` and return `true` works for me.